# Define the number of arguments in argparse

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I'm using `argparse` for passing to my script two different arguments (they are actually two files: an image and a json file) and use them for initialize my instance. And this works. But what if I would like to handle the case in which I pass the wrong number of arguments (less than two) or maybe the two arguments - the two files - doesn't exist?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='MyAgonism')
parser.add_argument('image')
parser.add_argument('json')
args = parser.parse_args()

MyAgonism = board(args.json, args.image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the numbers of arguments, and then check whether files exist.

```
def validate_num_of_args(args):
    return True if len(vars(args)) == 2 else False

def validate_image_arg(imagearg):
    has_found_image = True if os.path.exists(imagearg) else False
    has_valid_name = True if imagearg.endswith("jpeg") or imagearg.endswith("png") else False
    return has_found_image and has_valid_name

def validate_json_arg(jsonarg):
    ...
    ...

def validate_args(args):
    if validate_num_of_args(args):
    jsonarg, imagearg = args.json, args.image
        if validate_json_arg(jsonarg) and validate_image_arg(imagearg):
        pass
            # do your thing
        else:
        print "Error, invalid json/images files"
    else:
    print "Error, invalid number of arguments"
```

If your json and image files have naming conventions, you can also check the file names, like checking the files `startswith()` specific prefix, and `endswith()` specific suffix and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As written the `parser`will complain if you don't give it 2 arguments.  Try it!

As for checking that the arguments are valid - files exist, can be opened, etc - normal Python error checking and messages can be used.  `argparse` is a parser, not a complete programming script.